# SQL Join/Merge/Union multiple tables based on Date

Tags: sql, join, union

I have a database that has a Date in each table, which I want to combine. The problem I have is when one date is present in one table it does not show measures if that date is not present in other tables.

I am trying to connect/merge two SQL queries together based on their Date and PersonID.

I have Table A and B and want to create C.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do something like this, using a CTE and UNION ALL:

```
WITH tableC
AS
(


SELECT personID,
   person,
   datekey,
   date,
   SUM(sales) AS sales,
   NULL AS costs
FROM tableA
GROUP BY personID, person, datekey, date

UNION ALL

SELECT personID,
   person,
   datekey,
   date,
   NULL,
   SUM(costs) AS costs
FROM tableB
GROUP BY personID, person, datekey, date

)


SELECT personID,
   person,
   datekey,
   date,
   ISNULL(SUM(sales), 0) AS sales,
   ISNULL(SUM(costs),0) AS costs
FROM tableC
GROUP BY personID, person, datekey, date
ORDER BY datekey
```

Comment: @Sanguinus Glad I could help :)

Comment: The tag wiki says, "Answers to questions tagged with `SQL` should use ISO/IEC standard SQL" -- to be compliant, you need to change `NULL` to `CAST(NULL AS INTEGER)` and escape the reserved word `date` in double quotes as `"date"`. I also think you need to replace `ISNULL` with `COALESCE` to guarantee correct functionality.